# How can I edit/style only the "part of text" in all cells in Google Sheets?

Tags: google-sheets, formatting, string-formatting, google-sheets-formula, find-replace

This is my first question here, sorry if I sound too novice.

I'm trying to change a part of the text in all cells in a Google Sheet. I have hundreds of cells with text and also with `>>` symbols within the text.

What I want to do is to tell Google Sheet to find all instances of `>>` and edit all of them at once so they will be bold and in red.

Is this possible with a script?

Answer (score 0):

no, this is not possible. the only thing you can do is "find all instances" and replace them at once via <kbd>**`CTRL`**</kbd> + <kbd>**`H`**</kbd>. Google Sheets does not support mass partial-string formating within the same cell

- **https://webapps.stackexchange.com/a/131161/186471**
- **https://webapps.stackexchange.com/a/127678/186471**
- **https://webapps.stackexchange.com/a/130191/186471**